# How to Reduce latency when repeating the input audio from a microphone as the output audio to the speaker in Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-audiomanager, audiotrack, android-audiorecord

Just as an experiment I am trying to create an app that can repeat the input audio from a microphone as the output audio to the speaker. Till now I am able to do it with a latency of around 0.5 to 1 seconds. So if anyone has any idea about how to improve the code below to reduce latency.

From [Android high-performance audio - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2ZDp-eNrh4&t=446s) I saw that in-out latency can be as low as 20ms which is way lesser than what I am getting.

I tried searching on google and other questions on StackOverflow but most of the methods used there are deprecated in API level 26.

```
private fun recordAndPlay(){

    val audioManager = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    val rate = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE)

    val RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO
    val RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
    val RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = rate.toInt()
    val bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING)
    val BytesPerElement = 2


    val recorder = AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize * BytesPerElement)
    Log.e("Buffer , sample rate","*********** ${recorder.sampleRate}")

    recorder.startRecording()

    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build()
    val audioFormat = AudioFormat.Builder().setEncoding(RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING)
            .setSampleRate(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE).setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO).build()

    val recordingThread = Thread(Runnable {
        try {
            val sData = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            var at : AudioTrack? = AudioTrack.Builder()
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
                    .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize*2)
                    .build()
            while (true) {
                recorder.read(sData, 0, bufferSize)  //isRecording = false; onStop button
                at.play()
                if (at != null) {
                    at.write(sData, 0, sData.size)
                }
                at.stop()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread")

    recordingThread.start()
}
```

Thank you in advance.

---

Note: This question previously also addressed the issue of repeated echoing of the input sound. This issue was because of using the speaker of the phone rather than headphone causing feedback loop as mentioned in comments by lucky1928. That echoing was the fault of me overlooking the surrounding rather than any android related issue, so that part question has been removed. So when testing the above code please use headphones.

Comment: you should not call audiotrack play/stop everytime write. move the play/stop out from the loop!

Comment: @lucky1928 I tried it but it didn't work. On further observation, I can say that the ringing sound is the result of multiple echoes from the previous output.

Comment: Did you try to use headset? if you use speaker in phone, then the speaker output will be feed into mic also then cause echo definitely. If you need to use speaker, then you need to apply Echo Cancellation logic!

Comment: @lucky1928 It worked. I don't know how I took this thing for granted. Thanks a lot. By the way what is echo cancellation logic.

Comment: It's a technology mostly used in voice communication. you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981280/using-androids-build-in-acoustic-echo-cancellation